# Getting reference to IUnityContainer in static class

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I am trying to get a reference to my container in a static class within my domain so that I can do something like this:

```
public static class DomainEvents
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    // ...

    public static void Do<T>(T args) where T : IMyInterface
    {
        foreach (var s in Container.ResolveAll<IDoSomething<T>>())
            s.DoSomething(args);
    }
}
```

I obviously cannot inject it via constructor, is there any other way I can get a handle to it so I can resolve they registrations? Reading through some of the docs hasn't really been helpful. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this to be a static class? If you're using IoC, it should be just as easy to make this a regular class and inject it where needed.

Comment: @millimoose: The `DomainEvents` class is probably called by entities in a Domain Driven Design context and you can't (or shouldn't) do constructor injection in your entities. Still, it would be better to inject an `IDomainEvents` interface in the methods of entities (using method injection), instead of referencing a static class.

Comment: @Steven Even in that case, I'd probably do something like the following: http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/30/entity-framework-4-entity-dependency-injection/ (Assuming the ORM in use lets you hook into the entity lifecycle early enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just pass container in as a parameter to the function?  Or even better, this looks like a good candidate for an extension method.  If you change the function header as below, then you should be able to call Do directly on the container.  ie: container.Do(args);

```
public static void Do<T>(this IUnityContainer container, T args) where T : IMyInterface
{
    foreach (var s in container.ResolveAll<IDoSomething<T>>())
        s.DoSomething(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the extension method thing is what I am after. I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably practicing Domain Driven Design and reference this static `DomainEvents` class from within the method of your entities. Unfortunately this makes unit testing your entities much harder, since you now need to configure a Unity Container inside your tests.

Instead, use method injection on the methods of your entities and inject an `IDomainEvents` interface into those methods that need it. Although method injection is often sub optimal, constructor and property injection are out of the picture when dealing with entities, but method injection enabled the code to be loosely coupled:

```
public class Order
{
    public void CancelOrder(IDomainEvents de)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```